# NodeJs Pagination,recursive promise problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, web-scraping, promise

I am scraping multiple pages with cheerio and axios in node.js
I am having a hard time with Promises, can someone help me return the JSON if I hit the last page? Thanks!

```
const getWebsiteContent = async (url) => {
    await axios.get(url).then(res => {

        const $ = cheerio.load(res.data)

        pageNum = getTotalpages($);  // Get the pagination

        console.log(url);

        //Some scraping here
    })
    indexPage++; // Increment to the next page

    const nextPageLink = baseUrl + '&page=' + indexPage;      // get next page

    if (indexPage > pageNum) {
        var editedText = text.slice(0, text.length - 1);
        editedText += ']}';
        editedText = JSON.parse(editedText); // I want to return this and use elsewhere
        return editedText;
    }
    setTimeout(async () => {
        getWebsiteContent(nextPageLink); // Call itself
    }, 1000);
}
var myJSON= await getWebsiteContent(baseUrl); // something like this
```

Comment: I use `asyncUnfold` in some of [my answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A633183+asyncunfold). It's been awhile since I wrote those but it is well suited for this kind of problem. If I have time later tonight I can show you how to do this with async generators :D

Comment: Which JSON do you want to return?

Comment: 1:Thanks, Im waiting!
2:In the if(indexPage>pageNum) i concat the last bits of the JSON string,parse it into a JSON.I want to return that JSON.

Comment: Don't mix `async`/`await`, `.then()`, and passing callbacks. Wrap `setTimeout` in a promise, and decide on one style for handling promises.

Answer (score 1):

I would write `getPages` as an async generator -

```js
async function* getPages (href, initPage = 0) {
  const res = await axios.get(setPage(href, initPage))
  const $ = cheerio.load(res.data)
  const pages = getTotalpages($)
  yield { page: initPage, dom: $ }
  for (let p = initPage; p < pages; p++) {
    await sleep(1000)
    const r = await axios.get(setPage(href, p))
    yield { page: p, dom: cheerio.load(r.data) }
  }
}
```

This depends on helper `setPage` that manipulates the href page number using the [url module](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_class_urlsearchparams), which is much safer than hobbling together strings by hand -

```js
function setPage (href, page) {
  const u = new URL(href)
  u.searchParams.set("page", page)
  return u.toString()
}
```

And another helper, `sleep`, which prevents the mixing of `setTimeout` with `async`-based code. This allows us to easily pause between pages -

```js
async function sleep (ms) {
  return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))
}
```

Finally we write `scrape` which is a simple wrapper around `getPages`. This allows us to reuse the `getPages` function to scrape various elements as needed. A benefit of using this approach is that the caller can determine what happens with each page. Below we push to `result` array, but as another example we could write each page to disk using the `fs` module. Obviously this for you to decide -

```js
async function scrape (href) {
  const result = []
  for await (const {page, dom} of getPages(href)) {
    console.log("scraped page", page)  // some status message
    result.push(getSomeData(dom))      // get something from each page
  }
  return result
}

scrape(myUrl).then(console.log, console.error)
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using `then` with your async / await code.
pagination should look something like this:

```
let response = await axios.get(url)
let $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
// do some scraping
while(url = $('[rel=next]').attr('href')){
  response = await axios.get(url)
  $ = cheerio.load(response.data)
  // do more scraping
}
```

Comment: Nope, this wont solve my problem.
My output is like:
url/page1
undefined
url/page2
url/page3
END
My output should look like: 
url/page1
url/page2
url/page3
JSON
END